# Two Orderings of One List Using an Array of Pointers

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I'm trying to see sorting by using pointers. The original ordering of the data, and an alphabetical ordering accessed through an array of pointers. But there is wrong. The first printing shows ordered as alphabetical. It doesn't. I reviewed my insertion sort algorithm that is right for me. Where is my wrong ? Thank you for all appreciated answers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 3

void ins_sort(char *x_ptr[], int size);

int main(){   
    char x[MAX][20];
    char *x_ptr[MAX];
    int i;

    for(i=0 ; i < MAX ; i++){   
        scanf("%s" ,x[i]);
        x_ptr[i] = x[i];
    }

    ins_sort(x_ptr, MAX);

    printf("\n\n");
    for(i=0 ; i < MAX ; i++)
        printf("%s\n", x_ptr[i]);

    printf("\n\n");
    for(i=0 ; i < MAX ; i++)
        printf("%s\n", x[i]);

    return 0;
}

void ins_sort(char *x_ptr[], int size){
    int i,j;
    char *temp;

    for(i=1 ; i < size ; i++){
        temp = x_ptr[i];

        for(j=i ; j >= 0 && strcmp(temp, x_ptr[j-1]) < 0 ; j--){
            x_ptr[j] = x_ptr[j-1];
        }

        x_ptr[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Insertion_sort @NatashaDutta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
    for(j=i ; j > 0 && strcmp(temp, x_ptr[j-1]) < 0 ; j--){   /* >= must be > or j-1 = -1 */
```

The problem on its face with `j >= 0` is you were comparing `strcmp(temp, x_ptr[j-1])`. When `j = 0`, you compared `x_ptr[-1])` **and** assigned `x_ptr[0] = x_ptr[-1];`. You will also benefit from fixing your `scanf` format string. (I also added a `printf` so I would know what the code was prompting for.) Full changes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 3

void ins_sort(char *x_ptr[], int size);

int main(){   
    char x[MAX][20] = {{0}};
    char *x_ptr[MAX] = {NULL};
    int i = 0;

    for(i=0 ; i < MAX ; i++){   
        printf ("\n enter x_ptr[%d] : ", i);
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c" ,x[i]);
        x_ptr[i] = x[i];
    }

    ins_sort(x_ptr, MAX);

    printf("\n\n");
    for(i=0 ; i < MAX ; i++)
        printf("%s\n", x_ptr[i]);

    printf("\n\n");
    for(i=0 ; i < MAX ; i++)
        printf("%s\n", x[i]);

    return 0;
}

void ins_sort(char **x_ptr, int size){
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char *temp = NULL;

    for(i=1 ; i < size ; i++){
        temp = x_ptr[i];

        for(j=i ; j > 0 && strcmp(temp, x_ptr[j-1]) < 0 ; j--){
            x_ptr[j] = x_ptr[j-1];
        }

        x_ptr[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

**example:**

```
$ ./bin/ptrsort

 enter x_ptr[0] : bac

 enter x_ptr[1] : cab

 enter x_ptr[2] : abc


abc
bac
cab


bac
cab
abc
```

It was very apparent running your code through `gdb`, you were performing a comparison with `x_ptr[-1]` which caused you to stray off into `Undefined Behavior` and a `segfault` upon leaving the function (if not an outright crash):

```
39              for(j=i ; j >= 0 && strcmp(temp, x_ptr[j-1]) < 0 ; j--){
(gdb) info locals
i = 1
j = 0
```